# How to call Void method model in controller API in MVC?

Tags: c#

I am using Castle Windsor as DI and using reposity to access and implement the data layers. 
As I have implemented all the data access layer in my repo, it is time to call those methods in my API controller. However, when I do, I am getting error messages:

[image]

The method from repo is below:

```
public void CreateReport(TReportHeaderModel model)

        {

            using (var connection = new TReportEntitiesConnection())
            {

                connection.THeader.Add(new THeader()
                {

                    ClientID=model.ClientID,
                    ID=model.ID,
                    THeaderTitle=model.THeaderTitle,
                    RowNumber=model.RowNumber

                });


                foreach (var d in model.TReports)
                {
                    connection.TReport.Add(new TReport()
                    {

                        ID=d.ID,
                        TReportName=d.TReportName,
                        URL=d.URL,
                        RowNumber=d.RowNumber,



                    });

                }

                connection.SaveChanges();


            }



                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

and when I move it to my API controller as I have to pass these in HTTP Json Format:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public CreateReport([FromBody] TReportHeaderModel model) //Method must have a return type

    {


        try
        {
            _tReportingService.CreateReport(model);

            return new ActionResultModel()   //return void, must not be followed by object expression
            {
                Success = true,
                Message = "Report Successfully Created."
            };

        }


        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            return new ActionResultModel()
            {
                Success = false,
                Message = "Report not created.",
                Obj=ex.Message

            };


        }


    }
```

Comment: Functions in C# require a return type. In your case, just change it to `public ActionResultModel CreateReport([FromBody] TReportHeaderModel model)`.

Comment: I did not realize I was missing it. Thank you so much! If you post your answer in the post, I will make sure to vote it.

Answer (score 1):

your method should have a return type as per the Standard,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateReport([FromBody] TReportHeaderModel model) //Method must have a return type
{
     // Body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) here or your model class, it is not a [void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/void) it is a function, since it returns a value.

```
[HttpPost]
    public dynamic CreateReport([FromBody] TReportHeaderModel model) //Method must have a return type

    {
}
```